# Passing a query set with in a protected view in Django

Tags: django

I want to restrict user access to some pages in Django until they have signed in. This code below works fine except that I used to pass a query set in with the view so it could display all my books and this method doesn't work like that.

New view class (login required but no queryset sent?)

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'quotes/index.html'
    args = Book.objects.all()
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, args):
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(args)
```

I can't figure out how to pass my query `Book.objects.all()` along with this type of view. My view used to look like the below. As you can see it returns a queryset to be used by the template.
I am using this [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/) to try and provide login functionality.

Previously used view class (no login required):

```
class IndexView1(generic.ListView):
    template_name='quotes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return all the book objects"""
        return Book.objects.all()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you've done here. Why can't you continue to use the ListView subclass and override `dispatch()` there? Or why can't you use the login_required wrapper in the urlconf, as shown [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)?

Comment: Looks like I got a bit confused by the documentation. I didn't realise you could use dispatch like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two class based views you have mentioned `ListView` (older) and `TemplateView` are not equivalent. You can use the same `ListView` derived class as before as follows:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='quotes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'book_list'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, args):
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(args)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return all the book objects"""
        return Book.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, this explain a lot. Am I right in thinking that dispatch is only called when the user is not logged in but not called when the user has already logged in?

Comment: Every web request passes through [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch). So it is the right place to add additional security.

Comment: When using an id in my url i get this error dispatch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' even though i am logged in. Is there some way around this?